# Get a list of all rows from one table, that satisfies multiple criteria in two different tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 4 tables - `employee`, `company`, `employee_company`, and `action`.

`employee_company` contains `employee_id` and `company_id`, and `action`, among other things, contains `employee_id`.

Or, `employee_company` has a foreign key to `employee` and to `company`, and `action` has a foreign key to `employee`.

I'm trying to figure out a way to get a list of all employees that belong to companies with more than one employee, and no employee from that company has an entry in the `action` table.

I use `sequelize.js` as an orm, so either raw SQL or some way of doing it via sequelize would be helpful.

Comment: it would help if you mention the relation  between the tables, depending on them you have a simpler way of doing this or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to find the companies with multiple employees, and a left join to action:

```
select e.*
from (select company_id
      from employee_company
      group by conpany_id
      having count(*) > 1) c
join employee_company ec on ec.company_id = c.company_id
join employee e on ec.employee_id = e.id
left join action a on a.employee_id = e.id
where a.employee_id is null
```

This should be reasonably self explanatory, except perhaps the where clause - that filters out employees with actions, because left joined rows have all-null columns when there's no join.